# Efficient ways to solve complicated kinematics problems

Tags: simulations, computational-physics, quantum-computer

I'm curious about the range of approaches one can take to perform motion/kinematic simulations on many 3D objects.

Currently I am familiar with the iterative process of doing such a simulation, that might be used in a Game Engine:

1. placing objects in a 3D grid/scene
2. increasing a time index
3. iterating through all objects in the grid, and updating them based on forces/positions/etc.

I also recognize that there are some efficiency tricks to speed up these calculations. For example, the scene can be parceled into small sections and parallel threads can compute the physics of each section... however, all approaches seem to involve the computation of the velocity/acceleration/displacement for objects one at a time.

Generally speaking, are there other (efficient) approaches to solve for the physics of the entire scene simultaneously?

The motivation behind this question is trying to understand how nature seems to "solve" these differential questions of motion instantaneously and whether algorithms might be able to do the same. Could quantum computing be an answer?

Comment: If you need the trajectories of all objects, then, no, there is no other way than to calculate them all. If the objects don't interact by anything other than collisions, then the only part of the algorithm that is not O(n) is the collision detection and you seem to know how to speed that up with (oct-)tree methods.  If your objects are moving in a simple potential, then you may be able to skip the iterative numerical integration and use the precise solutions for the trajectory, but this may not even be cheaper. Nature does not solve differential equations, by the way, only we do that.